# How to paint only a part of a webpage when we translate a part?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, svg

I am facing a issue with over painting of my webpage as I am translating some parts too frequently ( every ~50ms). I tried using willChange attribute for the group I am translating but that didn't work. 
Please suggest. Let me know if further clarifications are required.

Comment: Please post a [MCVE]. It is quite difficult to debug imaginary code.

Comment: Note also that browsers already contain such repaint optimisations.